# How to clear time out in javascript function

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have two javascript functions and both work on click event. For each functions i have used set time out property. The problem is if first function is called and second function is called both timeouts are activated together. Is there any way to disable the timer of one function when one is enabled.

SCRIPT:

```
function overall(){
    $(".one").show();
    $(".two").hide();
    $(".three").hide();
    $(".four").hide();
    setTimeout(overall,1000);       
    }

function mobile(){
    $(".one").hide();
    $(".two").show();
    $(".three").hide();
    $(".four").hide();
    setTimeout(mobile,1000);        
    }
```

If this is the scenario what am i supposed to do? because both functions will be activated and i do not know how to turn off the time out when one is enabled

Comment: Can you check if a time out has been set?

Comment: you're not keeping track of the timer, you have to assign the return of `setTimeout` to a variable outside of the scope of the function.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` returns a value (a "timer handle"), which is a number other than `0`. You can cancel the timer by passing that value to `clearTimeout` before the timeout occurs.

So you can remember the timer handle for one or both of the timers you've scheduled (depending on what you need), and when something happens that makes you want to cancel one of those timers, call `clearTimeout` with the relevant handle.

---

You've asked for an example. Since it's still completely unclear to me what you want to cancel when, I'll take a guess: You want a call to `overall` to cancel any pending call to `mobile` and vice-versa:

```
// Variables to hold the timers
var overallTimer = 0,
    mobileTimer = 0;

function overall(){
    // If a pending call to mobile exists, cancel it
    if (mobileTimer) {
        clearTimeout(mobileTimer);
        mobileTimer = 0;
    }
    $(".one").show();
    $(".two").hide();
    $(".three").hide();
    $(".four").hide();
    // Schedule a call to ourselves, remember the timer handle
    overallTimer = setTimeout(overall,1000);       
    }

function mobile(){
    // If a pending call to overall exists, cancel it
    if (overallTimer) {
        clearTimeout(overallTimer);
        overallTimer = 0;
    }
    $(".one").hide();
    $(".two").show();
    $(".three").hide();
    $(".four").hide();
    // Schedule a call to ourselves, remember the timer handle
    mobileTimer = setTimeout(mobile,1000);       
    }
```

You could store the timers on the functions if you liked, although it doesn't really buy you much:

```
function overall(){
    // If a pending call to mobile exists, cancel it
    if (mobile.timer) {
        clearTimeout(mobile.timer);
        mobile.timer = 0;
    }
    $(".one").show();
    $(".two").hide();
    $(".three").hide();
    $(".four").hide();
    // Schedule a call to ourselves, remember the timer handle
    timer = setTimeout(overall,1000);       
    }
overall.timer = 0;

function mobile(){
    // If a pending call to overall exists, cancel it
    if (overall.timer) {
        clearTimeout(overall.timer);
        overall.timer = 0;
    }
    $(".one").hide();
    $(".two").show();
    $(".three").hide();
    $(".four").hide();
    // Schedule a call to ourselves, remember the timer handle
    mobile.timer = setTimeout(mobile,1000);       
    }
mobile.timer = 0;
```

Comment: @jibindcruz: It doesn't change the answer. Remember the handle (the return value of `setTimeout`), and use `clearTimeout` if you want to cancel that timer.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to?

Comment: @jibindcruz: I've added an example.

Comment: See what if there is more than two functions? this is basically for just two functions right?

Comment: @jibindcruz: If there are more than two functions, then you have to do a bit more work keeping track of things, cancelling things when you want to, etc. I've given you the tools, it's down to *you* to use them.

Comment: see in the second function its checking if the timer is set right? so if i want the second function to keep on being called after one second the method you are using would prevent it na?

Comment: @jibindcruz: No, you haven't used any timers to schedule calls to the second function. Both of the `setTimeout` calls you have in your code call `overall`, neither calls `mobile`. Again: You now know everything you need to know to use timers effectively, you just have to put the effort in to make them do what you want them to do. This isn't complicated: `setTimeout` returns a value you can use to cancel it if you need to.

Comment: sorry my bad. The second function calls itself. If i have n number of functions everything should call itself and disable the previously enabled timer

Comment: @jibindcruz: Then use two separate variables for storing the timers, one for each function. I've updated the example.